# Ambiguity on overload resolution between Action and unit -> unit types in F#

Tags: f#

Given the following fragment:

```
type Foo() =
    static member Test (act : unit -> unit) = act()
    static member Test (act : Action) = Foo.Test act.Invoke
```

I get an error on the final line stating: A unique overload for method 'Test' could not be determined based on type information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed.

Unfortunately, the type annotation `(act.Invoke : unit -> unit)` does not resolve the ambiguity, and I cannot find an annotation that does fix it. I would like the `Action` version of be a wrapper round the `->` version. My particular use case is defining a class that will be called from both F# and C#, so I want it to work natively from both languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

F# inserts the conversion to `Action` for you, so you could (in theory) get by with one method.

```
type Foo() =
    static member Test (act : Action) = act.Invoke()

Foo.Test (fun () -> ())
```

I can't figure out how to force the compiler to choose between `Action` and `unit -> unit`. Two other options:

1. make the `Action` overload the primary and do `Foo.Test(Action(act))`
2. put the logic in a third function which is called from the public methods

But my recommendation would be a single method taking `Action`. Since the conversion is automatic, interop, in a sense, is free.

Comment: Maybe it's cheating, but this would sort-of convert `Action` to an F# function: `let cvtAct (a:Action) = fun () -> a.Invoke()`

Comment: @JoelMueller: Unfortunately, that still won't help the compiler pick the right overload. I assume, because of the auto conversion from `unit -> unit` to `Action`, it can't distinguish between the two.

Comment: +1, since `Action` *is* the `unit -> unit` delegate, this is the right answer.

Comment: You can convert an ``Action`` to an F# function with ``act.Invoke`` which produces a function of ``unit -> unit``

Comment: I should have said: I can't figure out how to force the compiler to choose between them.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel says, you can probably just skip the first overload since F# will automatically insert a delegate constructor when a method taking a delegate is applied to an F# function value (see section [8.13.6](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc321997181) of the spec).

If you really wanted to define a type with the same surface area as your example, you could take advantage of the fact that let-bound functions do not include the type-directed conversion (only method invocations do):

```
type Foo() = 
    static let test act : unit = act()
    static member Test act = test act
    static member Test (act : System.Action) = test act.Invoke
```

Doing this isn't very useful, though, since you will run into the same problem if you try to call the first overload from outside of the class as you ran into when trying to define the second overload.